# When added to cells error and not working

Tags: jquery

When first opening the selected message is displayed in the message.
    new message does not appear when I press the Add button. What is the problem

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetsadri/9K3q6/1/)

Select a message from the list on the right side is typing a message.
add the 2nd time I push message does not come when I select a message in the list

HTML

```
<table class="color"  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" id="myTable">
    <tr class="user">
        <td >
            <select name="a" id="selectMe">
                <option value="" selected></option>
                <option value="1">Message</option>
                <option value="2">Not Message</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td id="group">
            Message</td>
    </tr>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Rows" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

CSS

```
<style>
#group {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
}
</style>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var counter = 0;

            $("#addrow").on("click", function () {

                counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

                var newRow = $("<tr>");
                var cols = "";

                cols += '<td><select id="selectMe" name="a" ><option value="" ></option><option value="1" >Message</option><option value="2">Not Message </option></select></td><td id="group">mesage<</td>';

                cols += '<td><input type="button"  value="x" ></td>';
                newRow.append(cols);
                if (counter == 4) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
                $("table.color").append(newRow);
                counter++;
            });




            $("table.color").on("click", ".buttons", function (event) {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                calculateGrandTotal();

                counter -= 1
                $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Rows");
            });


        });




$('.user').each(function(){
    var parent = this,
        group = $('#group', parent);
    $('#selectMe', parent).on('change', function(){
        var indis = $(':selected', this).index();
        if ( indis > 0 ){
            indis -= 1;
            group.hide().filter(':eq(' + indis + ')').fadeIn(300);
        } else {
            group.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

what I want. When I press the add button also to give new posts

Comment: All your rows give the same ID `selectMe` to the menu. IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Also, your selectors are all messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$(".user").each()` loop is only operating on the elements that are there when the page is first loaded. DIVs that are added later using the add button are not processed, so the `change` handler is never added.

To implement event binding on dynamically added elements, you must use *delegation*. Also, you shouldn't give elements the same IDs, you should use classes for similar elements. So change `id="selectMe"` and `id="group"` to `class="selectMe"` and `class="group"` in the HTML, and change the CSS to use `.group`. The click handler then becomes:

```
$('.color').on('change', '.selectMe', function () {
    var group = $(this).closest("td").siblings(".group");
    var indis = $(':selected', this).index();
    if (indis > 0) {
        indis -= 1;
        group.hide().filter(':eq(' + indis + ')').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        group.hide();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9K3q6/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate the `click` event and specify the target input type (`button`):

```
    $("table.color").on("click", "input[type='button']", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();

        counter -= 1
        $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Rows");
    });
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E2yWF/)

Comment: thanks, but not the problem.
Select a message from the list on the right side is typing a message.
add the 2nd time I push message does not come when I select a message in the list

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? I am not sure i follow you

Comment: see the demo > http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetsadri/9K3q6/1/ 
1. list menu > message show message and add rows button ready
2. list menu > message not show message